# jsf inputtext not setting values

Tags: java, jsf

I am stumped. I have a form with inputtexts that I want the user to populate, and when they hit the add button, set those properties using the f:param. The values keep coming back as null when I try to get them from the context:

```
        <h:form>
        <h1 align="center" style="font-size: 12pt; color: green">Enter the details for the new product</h1>
        <br/>
        <div align="center">
            <h:outputLabel id="productNameLabel"
                           value="Product Name " />
            <h:inputText id="productName" value="#{product.productName}" />
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div align="center">
            <h:outputLabel id="productDescriptionLabel"
                           value="Product Description " />
            <h:inputText id="description" value="#{product.description}" />
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div align="center">
            <h:outputLabel id="productQuantity"
                           value="Product Quantity " />
            <h:inputText id="quantity" value="#{product.quantity}" />
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="welcome">
                <f:param name="creating" value="true"/>
                <f:param name="name" value="#{product.productName}" />
                <f:param name="description" value="#{product.description}" />
                <f:param name="quantity" value="#{product.quantity}" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: how do you get from the context? post the code

Comment: Re-read my answer on your previous question, particularly the 2nd note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896784/not-a-valid-method-expression-in-jsf